# conditional use of indexOf function

Tags: javascript, url, query-string

I'm using a script that searches a URL for a query string and ignores the query if it is found. The script works, but only when there is a query string present. The error I am getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined` so it's obvious where the error is occuring, I'm just not sure how to solve it. I need to only execute `indexOf` when a query string is found, correct? How can I achieve this?

Here is the JS causing the error:

```
var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
var fname = href;
var query = href.indexOf("?");

if (query !== -1) {
    fname = href.substr(0, query);
}
```

I think to fix this I just need to conditionally execute the `href.indexOf("?");` portion of the script, but all my attempts thus far have failed.

Comment: _all my attempts thus far have failed_ well, what have you tried?

Comment: Since you're looking at the `href` **attribute**, you should be able to just look at the `search` **property**, which represents the `href`'s querystring. For example, `var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href = "http://www.example.com/?var=val"; alert(a.search);`

Comment: You're trying to debug an error where OP doesn't say what he wants to do. Is this script running on an `A` tag? Do you want to check `window.location`? simple `var href = jQuery(this).attr('href') || '';` will remove the error, but it won't fix the logic behind it.

Comment: in weak-type languages, it's usually quicker/simpler to massage than condition:  href.indexOf("?") can safely be String(href).indexOf("?"); you can also safely use the call form: "".indexOf.call(href , "?" )

Comment: `href && href.indexOf("?");` solves your core problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test for "?" should work - perhaps your href is empty?

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9gnB4/)

```
function getFName(link) {
  var href = link.href || "no href found";
  return href.split("?")[0];
}

var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "http://www.google.com/search?q=something";
var fname = getFName(a);
window.console && console.log(fname);
a.href = "http://www.google.com/search";
fname = getFName(a)
window.console && console.log(fname);
```

Just for your information, there is a search attribute of the link you can test if you must know if there was a querystring

Test the search property instead of href

```
var query = this.search;
var fname = query?this.href.split("?")[0]:this.href;
```

Comment: The second portion of your answer worked just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether href is undefined before calling indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dqzhz/

```
var url = getURL("http://www.example.com?q=1&x=2");
alert(url);

function getURL(link) {
    url = document.createElement('a');
    url.href = link;
    return url.protocol + "//" + url.host;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/attr/ :

> As of jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set.

`undefined.indexOf(...)` will crash, but you could fall back on an empty string like this :

```
var query = (href || '').indexOf('?');
```

It means "something true or an empty string" :

```
undefined || '' -> ''
       "" || '' -> ''
      "a" || '' -> "a"
```

Answer (score -2):

this function returns the value of a querystring or empty string if not found.

```
function getQueryParameterByName(name) {

            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/gi, "\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp(regexS, "i");
            var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
            if (results == null)
                return "";
            else
                return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/gi, " "));
}
```

Comment: Insane waste of regex when you can return link.search. In any case OP is not interested in the querystring, but in the URL without it

Comment: Well thats pretty easy. Guess I was tired when reading the question.